# LSTM model has constant accuracy and doesn't variate

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

i'm stuck as you can see, with my lstm model. I'm trying to predict the amount of tons to produce per month. When i run the model to train the accuracy is almost constant, it has a minimal variation like:

```
 0.34406
 0.34407
 0.34408
```

I tried different combination of activations, initializers and parameters, and the acc don't increase.
I don't know if the problem here is my data, my model or this value is the max acc the model can reach.

Here is the code (if you notice some libraries unused, its because i made some changes by the first version)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler, RobustScaler
from sklearn import preprocessing

import keras
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

%matplotlib inline
from plotly.offline import iplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.offline as pyoff
import plotly.graph_objs as go


df_ventas = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/proyectoPanimex/DEOPE.csv', parse_dates=['Data Emissão'], index_col=0, squeeze=True)
#df_ventas = df_ventas.resample('M').sum().reset_index()
df_ventas = df_ventas.drop(columns= ['weekday', 'month'], axis=1)
df_ventas = df_ventas.reset_index()

df_ventas = df_ventas.rename(columns= {'Data Emissão':'Fecha','Un':'Cantidad'})
df_ventas['dia'] = [x.day for x in df_ventas.Fecha]
df_ventas['mes']=[x.month for x in df_ventas.Fecha]
df_ventas['anio']=[x.year for x in df_ventas.Fecha]
df_ventas = df_ventas[:-48]
df_ventas = df_ventas.drop(columns='Fecha')

df_diff = df_ventas.copy()
df_diff['cantidad_anterior'] = df_diff['Cantidad'].shift(1)
df_diff = df_diff.dropna()
df_diff['diferencia'] = (df_diff['Cantidad'] - df_diff['cantidad_anterior'])
df_supervised = df_diff.drop(['cantidad_anterior'],axis=1)

#adding lags
for inc in range(1,31):
    nombre_columna = 'retraso_' + str(inc)
    df_supervised[nombre_columna] = df_supervised['diferencia'].shift(inc)

df_supervised = df_supervised.dropna()
df_supervisedNumpy = df_supervised.to_numpy()

train = df_supervisedNumpy

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
X_train = scaler.fit(train)

train = train.reshape(train.shape[0], train.shape[1])
train_scaled = scaler.transform(train)

X_train, y_train = train_scaled[:, 1:], train_scaled[:, 0:1]
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1])

#LSTM MODEL
model = Sequential()

act = 'tanh'
actF = 'relu'

model.add(LSTM(200, activation = act, input_dim=34, return_sequences=True ))
model.add(Dropout(0.15))

#model.add(Flatten())

model.add(LSTM(200, activation= act))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

#model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(200, activation= act))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Dense(1, activation= actF))

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00001)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 100, 
                epochs = 50, verbose = 1)

hist = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
hist['Epoch'] = history.epoch
hist
```

History plot:

```
    loss        acc         Epoch
0   0.847146    0.344070    0
1   0.769400    0.344070    1
2   0.703548    0.344070    2
3   0.698137    0.344070    3
4   0.653952    0.344070    4
```

As you can see the only value that change its loss, but what is going on with Acc?. I'm starting with machine learning, and i have no more knowledge to can see my errors. Thanks!

Comment: Relu is never a good idea for outputs, and never a good idea with 1 unit either.

Comment: Thanks, I will never forget it!

Comment: @DanielMöller Incorrect, it is useful if you want to predict positive values (for regression).

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, it will freeze, you will have lots of outputs stuck at zero, and worse, these will not influence the weights towards increasing because their backpropagation is killed.

Comment: While in the middle of the net, the zeros end up causing a change in subsequent layers, and due to the high variation may change often, that's not true in the output. The zeros will not bring any good, and variation/randomness will not be usefull because they're outputs, you want precision in the outputs.

Comment: @DanielMöller Sure, it can have dying ReLU issues, but claiming is never a good idea is an exaggeration, you can use any variation with non-zero gradients, if the point is to predict positive values at the output.

Comment: Well, those variations are not "ReLU".... they're prelu, elu, softplus, etc.

Answer (score 1):

- A `Dense(1, activation='softmax')` will **always** freeze and not learn anything
- A `Dense(1, activation='relu')` will **very probably** freeze and not learn anything
- A `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')` is ideal for classification (binary) problems and somewhat good for regression with values between 0 and 1.
- A `Dense(1, activation='tanh')` is somewhat good for regression with values between -1 and 1
- A `Dense(1, activation='softplus')` is somewhat good for regression with values between 0 and +infinite
- A `Dense(1, actiavation='linear')` is good for regression in general with no limits (but it's highly recommended that the data be normalized before)

---

For regression, you can't use accuracy, but the metrics `'mae'` and `'mse'` don't provide "relative" difference, they provide "absolute" mean difference, one linear, the other squared.

Comment: i'm gonna try it, wait a moment.

Comment: the Linear Activation, it makes a real change, thanks a lot! Can you recommend a book or article to learn more about this?

Answer (score 0):

Your output activation should be `linear` for continuous prediction or `softmax` for classification. Also multiply your learning rate by 100. Your loss should be `mean_absolute_error`. You could also easily divide your `lstm` neurons by a factor of 10. The `tanh` should be replaced by `relu` or the likes.

For your accuracy problem, it makes no sense to use accuracy, since you're not trying to classify. For metrics, you can use `mae`. You're trying to know how far the prediction is from the actual target, on a continuous scale. Accuracy is for categories, not continuous data.

Comment: "sigmoid", not "softmax", it's 1 unit. ---- "softplus" is a good replacement for "relu" if the 0+ behavior was intended.

Comment: Nicolas, i tried the things you say to me and it has no real change, but has a minimal increase from 0.3441 to 0.3448. Before you comment it stucked to 0.3441

Comment: I really tried almost all combinations, but it has no increase of 0.34. Can the problem be the standarization?

Comment: @NicolasGervais mmm i understand but how can i know if my model has learned?, when i use it to predict "model.predict" the predicted value is very bad.

Comment: @NicolasGervais this is the result  

    loss: 0.0638 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0638

Comment: Ok so your problem is solved. That's basically a 6% error margin between your targets and your predictions. Glad I could help!

Comment: @NicolasGervais I have a doubt, i know this things are predictions, but the tons to predict were 140, and the real tons value was 800 hahahah. I have to learn too much...

Comment: @NicolasGervais I restart the environment and i got -> loss: 0.7426 - mean_absolute_error: 0.7426